# game logic in js

Tags: javascript, algorithm

i explain my probleme : 
i have a worm game like this [image]

i have to go to the next level if i hit SUCCESSIVELY 10 worm
i have 3 points live, if i dont hit a worm live = live -1, 0 live : game over

in the 2nd level there 2 warms shown simultaneous, level 3 there are 3 shown ..

i cant find a solution to count the 10 successive hits.

can you tell me how to proceed?
thank you.

Comment: Are you just asking how to perform the most basic operations on a variable such as incrementing/decrementing and comparing it to another number?!

Comment: Is the variable you are trying increment outside of the "level scope"?  Try to take it up to the "game scope".

Comment: You managed to make elaborate graphics, but you can't figure out how to track a variable?

Answer (score 2):

Forgive me if i'm mistaken but why can't you just track it with a variable?

```
var lives = 3;
var streakcount = 0;
while(streakcount < 10 && lives > 0)
{
    do_level_logic();
    if(hit)
        streakcount++;
    else if(miss)
    {
        streakcount = 0;
        lives--;
    }
}
```

can you elaborate a little bit more on specifically what you need?

Or maybe you need a function where you have a certain time limit to get another hit in order to continue the streak.

Answer (score 0):

```
define streak=0
on success_hit_event streak++
if streak==10 level_up
on miss_hit_event { streak=0; live-- }
```